# Why AFTER UPDATE (FOR EACH ROW) trigger fires before (NOT DEFERRABLE) integrity constraint checks?

Tags: oracle, triggers, constraints, integrity

I am learning triggers using Oracle 12c `HR` sample schema and `Oracle Develop PL/SQL Program Units` student guide. Oracle says that the trigger execution model is:

1. Execute all BEFORE STATEMENT triggers.
2. Loop for each row affected by the SQL statement:
3. Execute all BEFORE ROW triggers for that row.
4. Execute the DML statement **AND PERFORM INTEGRITY CONSTRAINT CHECKING FOR THAT ROW**.
5. Execute all AFTER ROW triggers for that row.
6. Execute all AFTER STATEMENT triggers.

The sample HR schema has an `EMPLOYEES` table with a `DEPARTMENT_ID` FK recerencing a `DEPARTMENT_ID` PK in a `DEPARTMENTS` table.

Correctly, if I try to insert a record in `EMPLOYEES` having a FK value that does not exist among the PKs in `DEPARTMENTS`, I will get a `ORA-02291: integrity constraint (HR.EMP_DEPT_FK) violated - parent key not found` error.

As a proof of concept, I create the following **BEFORE** UPDATE trigger to insert the missing record in `DEPARTMENTS` and avoid the integrity constraint violation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER employee_dept_fk_trg
  BEFORE UPDATE OF department_id ON employees 
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO departments (department_id, department_name) VALUES(:new.department_id,'Dept '||:new.department_id);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    NULL; -- mask exception if department already exists
END;
```

It works fine (I can insert a non existent FK as the corresponding PK would be created first).

The studying material says then that we could make the `HR.EMP_DEPT_FK` constraint `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` in order to postpone the integrity check at the moment of the final `COMMIT` and not at the end of each `INSERT` statement (see item #4 in list), and so create an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger rather than a `BEFORE UPDATE` one like the previous.

Are there any advantages of doing so versus just using a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger?

Before altering the `HR.EMP_DEPT_FK` constraint setting it `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`, I wanted to verify the assertion in item #4, so I created an identical `AFTER UPDATE` trigger and I tried to insert a non existent FK in the employees table: I RECEIVED NO `ORA-02291` ERROR and the new PK record in `DEPARTMENTS` table has been created! **It seems that the `AFTER UPDATE` trigger executes before any integrity constraint check**, while that should happen after! (see item #5)

Could you help me on this topic, please?

Thank you all,
Pino

Comment: Did you drop the   BEFORE trigger? Otherwise it is still executed and inserts the dept_id

Comment: A trigger should not be used to ensure integrity - this will usually fail. Actually your question does not make any sense, a trigger is used for other purposes than a constraint.

Comment: I didn't drop the BEFORE trigger, I hust edited it changing "BEFORE" to "AFTER". I am studying triggers and I want to test and verify all oracle assertions. Oracle says that the integrity violation check occurs between before row and after row, so i tested it but, as I wrote, I found the identical behaviour, so I think my question makes perfect sense because its purpose is a proof of concept. :)

Comment: You are learning Oracle PL/SQL. Don't waste your time to find errors if Oracle documentation or debug functional details. Again, don't use triggers to enforce integrity. Thus your question is not relevant, the trigger does not make any sense (i.e. it is very poor design). Maybe when you become a Oracle guru you may investigate this again.

Comment: I'm not trying to hunt and seek Oracle faults, instead I'm trying to understand the difference between a BEFORE UPDATE ROW and AFTER UPDATE ROW. Oracle documentation sounded good but (as I use to test every assumption) it revealed a weird behaviour. I agree that "solving" integrity constraint using triggers is poor programming, I just wanted to understand what was happening behind the curtains...